# J-Query printer (jQuery.printElement) can't print multiple pages in opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, printing, opera

I'm using  `jQuery.printElement` plugin for printing purpose.

The javascript is as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#button").click(function() {
             printElement({ leaveOpen: true, printMode: 'popup' });
         });

     });
 function printElement(options){
     $('#printablediv').printElement(options);
 }

</script>
```

---

html form input is as following:

```
<input type="button" value="Print" id="button" />
```

---

html printable div is as following:

```
<div id = "printablediv"> Some printable stuffs here </div>
```

The printer works fine in all browsers but opera can't print all the contents within a predefined  `div`. It only prints the contents of first page / top portion of a `div` as covered / displayed by the browser window although all the contents of that 'div` is displayed in it's print preview window.

Any idea?

Comment: Interesting issue, it sounds like a bug. Can you post a link to a page that shows the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's an opera bug. Thanks,

Comment: It would be nice to have an example page - it would help us at Opera when we try to fix this problem :)

Comment: I would like to interact anonymously. If you provide me your ftp username and password, I shall upload the script to your server. Thanks,

Comment: Could you simply send me an E-mail? :) Same user name as on stackoverflow @ myopera.com. If you think that isn't anonymous enough I'll arrange some FTP upload for you.

Comment: That's all right. I shall e-mail you the script as soon as possible after I isolate it from my application. Thanks,

Comment: I've e-mail you the script. Your opinion shall be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Learner,
as far as I can see the result desired has been achieved, not sure if for a new release of Opera or the plugin itself.

If you still have issues, we can all profit from details on versions used.